# Lines > Polygon artifacts

Tags: qgis, polygon, polygon-creation

I am trying to make polygons from a set of boundaries from an SVG file with closed polylines I downloaded off wikipedia.

1) convert SVG to DXF via Inkscape
2) import into QGIS (shows polyline data)
3) Lines > Polygon

somehow the result seems to generate these bad polygons with defects - I attach a screenshot here

I tried re-exporting the file to DXF again, and putting it into a 3d CAD suite (rhino 5). I managed to join the lines without any changes. re-export to DXF, reimport into QGIS, remake polyllines and I get the same result

does anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: This is symptomatic of double digitized points and/or bowtie intersections. There is a really good post http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84820/i-would-like-to-know-how-to-clean-topological-errors that will help you. When faced with this in ArcMap a repair geometry will usually fix the lines before importing. Another trick that can help is putting a fishnet over it and intersecting (leave the lines in), this will break the lines down into smaller chunks so you can find the bad parts quicker and fix in the original.